# What happens when you remove a value from the middle of an array?

Tags: lua

If I have an array like this:

```lua
local array = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```

And I remove the second element like this:

```lua
array[2] = nil
```

Would this send `array[3]` and any larger index to the hash part of a table? Or does it just leave a hole in the array portion?

Answer (score 2):

It will add a another border.

This has a few effects:

1. you can no longer use `ipairs` to get all your elements as `ipairs` will stop at the first border
2. the length operator `#` will no longer give you the number of elements in that table as it may return any border.
3. `table.concat` will raise an error *invalid value (nil) at index 2 in table for 'concat'*
4. some functions in the table library will no longer work for  values after the border

See

- [length operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7)
- [ipairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-ipairs)
- [table manipulation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.6)

Comment: Sorry @Piglet - Point 3 depends on how you use ```concat``` - I believe concat is like a scalpel for keys that are numbers - For example: ```table.concat(arg,'',0,0)``` puts out exactly what i want ;-) - And moreover with several different blocks of keys in sequence you or we can concat whatever we want

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi that's the error message you get for the OP's example array. you can give an optional start and end index to work around gaps  but it will fail for any range that contains a nil value. `table.concat(arg,'',0,0)` is nonsense, just use `arg[0]`

Comment: Based on chapter 4, from here http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf, lua has an array part and hash part. According to the article, lua doesn't use a "pure" associative array, although that might've been the case before 5.0. My question was more of how lua will handle the hole, does it just leave it as a hole (nil)? Or does it reallocate any greater index to the hash part?

Comment: sorry I didn't recall this paper. so your question is about the innner workings of Lua, not about the consequences in a script. I suggest you ask it over the mailing list https://www.lua.org/lua-l.html  Lua's devs answer questions here from time to time but getting in touch with them directly is probably more successful.

Answer (score 1):

That leaves a hole.
Therefore exists: `table.remove()`

You have to specialize your tools than.
For example a `tprint()` that can handle it...

```
tprint=function(tab,...)
local args={...}
local start=args[1]
local stop=args[2]

if type(args[1])=='number' and type(args[2])=='number' then
 warn('Using numbers for table print out')
 for i=start,stop do
  io.write(string.format('%d = %s\n',i,tab[i])):flush()
  if start==stop then return tab[i] end
 end
else
 warn('Using pairs() for table print out')
 for key,value in pairs(tab) do
  io.write(string.format('%s = %s\n',key,value)):flush()
 end
end

end
```

Than you can do things like...

```
>tprint(arg)
Lua warning: Using pairs() for table print out
1 = -W
2 = -i
3 = -e
4 =  dofile('/root/lua/tprint.lua')
0 = /root/bin/lua
1618128658 = It is alive!!!
1618129059 = function: 0x566bf0f0
1618129084 = function: 0x566bfba0
1618128894 = tprint
>tprint(arg,1618128658,1618128658)
Lua warning: Using numbers for table print out
1618128658 = It is alive!!!
It is alive!!!
```

...or a sequence from 0 to 4 ...

```
>tprint(arg,0,4)
Lua warning: Using numbers for table print out
0 = /root/bin/lua
1 = -W
2 = -i
3 = -e
4 =  dofile('/root/lua/tprint.lua')
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question asked. also this is pretty special and might not be easy to understand for a beginner. it introduces a lot of noise that is not related to the question. `table.concat for a single element could be simply replaced by table indexing and an implicit or explicit conversion to string imho

Comment: Yes - I agree - And replace ( correct ;-) ) concat to ```tab[i]```

Answer (score 0):

you can put remaining entries into a new list, to essentially close that gap

```
newarray = {}
for i = 1, #array do
    if array[i] then 
        newarray[ #newarray ] = array[i]
    end
end
```

or nudge them all down one position, using multiple assignment to flip-flop entries ( index 3 into 2, 2 into 3... ) leaving that `nil` as the final entry, so things behave as expected.

```
for i = 1, #array do
    if not array[i] then 
        array[i], array[i+1]  = array[i+1], array[i]
    end
end
```

Comment: please note that the length operator will return any border. it is not necessarily the number of elements in the table unless the table is a sequence. it will work in many cases but in won't in many as well. your second snippet fails for the trivial case of `{1, nil, 3, nil}` or multiple subsequent nils. as you'll also move nil values back

Comment: well yea, I was assuming you'd clear the list directly after removing an entry, not waiting for multiple holes to accrue.  but yea, it's good a point that others might need to know.

Comment: if you just want to remove a single element use `table.remove` it does the shifting for you

Comment: if it's your list, and that option is available, sure.  forego `nil` & multiple assignment. `remove()` will be more performant.  however, the question was specifically about `nil` entries in a list.  so, if your list is being perforated by a function that you don't have control over, use what works.

Comment: actually the question was what happens if you introduce a gap in a sequence, not how to remove it. nevermind, not here to argue ;) if you don't want your table to be perforated you should probably prevent this using a metatable.